Lark grammar: precedence in array stranding
I'm writing a Lark grammar for a subset of APL (see below). APL has very few precedence rules. Execution is right to left, and functions are infix.
5 × 5 - 2

means 5×(5-2), not (5×5)-2.
Vectors are formed by simple "stranding", values separated by space:
1 2 3 4 5

Group elements by parentheses to form a "list of lists":
(1 2)(3 4)(5 6)

Functions are special characters, such as ⍴ for "shape" and ⍳ for range. Thus, to form a 2x2 matrix, I can say
2 2⍴⍳4

which could be interpreted as reshape([2, 2], list(range(4))) in Python. In APL, functions have "long scope" to the right, and short scope to the left.
Certain symbols represent higher-order functions, known as operators. They take operands that are either functions, or arrays, and can be seen as a means of composition:
+⌿ 1 2 3 4

means "sum-reduce" an array. Here, the symbol ⌿ is the reduction operator, which is given the + function as its operand to form the sum-reduce derived function. This is where APL has a different precedence from strict right-left: operator-operand binds tighter than everything else, except array stranding.
@ is an operator that can take arrays as operands both to the left and right.
(1 2 3@4 5 6) 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

will replace the values found at the indices specified by the right operand (4 5 6), with the values of the left operand (1 2 3) in the argument passed to the resulting derived function.
The grammar correctly parses most of what I throw at it, EXCEPT that last example, which it treats as an array, erroneously giving
'(1 2 3 @ 4 5 6)7 5 4 10 3 6 9 2 1 8', body
  array
    apply
      1
      bind_dyadic
        array
          2
          3
        @
        array
          4
          5
      6
    7
    5
    4
    10
    3
    6
    9
    2
    1
    8
),

instead of
'(1 2 3 @ 4 5 6)7 5 4 10 3 6 9 2 1 8', body
    apply
      bind_dyadic
        array
          1
          2
          3
        @
        array
          4
          5
          6
    array
      7
      5
      4
      10
      3
      6
      9
      2
      1
      8
),

Here's my current grammar (Earley):
?start: body

?sep: (NEWLINE | "⋄")+

body: sep? (expr sep)* expr sep?
?expr: mo_expr | do_expr | arr_expr | func_expr |  guard 
?atom: NUMBER | DFNARG | AIDENT | ESCAPED_STRING | "(" arr_expr ")"

?array: atom+
?arr_expr: arg | assign

?train: fork
      | derived fork -> atop

?func: FUNCTION | FIDENT | "(" func_expr ")" | block

?monadic_op: MOIDENT | MONADIC_OP | "(" mo_expr ")"

?dyadic_op: DOIDENT | DYADIC_OP | "(" do_expr ")"

?derived: func                             -> func
        | operand monadic_op               -> bind_monadic
        | operand dyadic_op (array|func)   -> bind_dyadic

?operand: array|derived

func_expr: train -> train
         | fassign -> fassign

fassign: FIDENT "←" func_expr

mo_expr: MONADIC_OP
       | mo_assign

do_expr: DYADIC_OP
       | do_assign

fork: derived              -> func
    | derived derived fork -> fork
    | noassign derived fork -> atop

?arg: array
    | (array|noassign)? derived arr_expr -> apply

assign: AIDENT "←" arr_expr
mo_assign: MOIDENT "←" mo_expr
do_assign: DOIDENT "←" do_expr

block: "{" body "}"

guard: expr ":" expr 

noassign: (array|noassign)? derived noassign

FUNCTION: /[⊥⊤⊣⊢○~≢≡⍸↑↓∊⍉⊖⌽⍴⍳+×÷⍪,⌈|⌊\-*\/∨∧<>=≠≤≥\/⍋⍒?]/
MONADIC_OP: /[¨⌿⍀⍨]/
DYADIC_OP: /[@⍥⍤⍣∘]/
AIDENT: /[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*/
MOIDENT: /_[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9_]*(?<!_)/ 
DOIDENT: /_[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*_/
DFNARG: /[⍺⍵]/
FIDENT: /[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*/

NUMBER: /¯?\d+(\.\d+)?([eE][+¯]?\d+)?/
_STRING_INNER: /.*?/
_STRING_ESC_INNER: _STRING_INNER /(?<!\\)(\\\\)*?/ 
ESCAPED_STRING : "'" _STRING_ESC_INNER "'"

%import common.NEWLINE
%import common.WS

%ignore WS

